# Error al enviar mis mensajes con las función mail de PHP

Tags: php, email, mail

Estoy queriendo enviar mensajes de email a los suscriptores de mi blog, pero por alguna razón la función solo funciona con los primeros email, luego los email no les llegan a los demás usuarios y cuando entro a mi hosting me encuentro con este mensaje donde me dice que no se han podido enviar los mensajes de email.
[image: Error de mensajes de email en el hosting]

Estoy usando un hosting compartido `cpanel` y al revisar los envíos de email, me muestra esos errores donde dice que no se han podido enviar los email.

**NOTA** Los email están bien escritos y son email que funcionan, ya que son correos míos con los que he estado haciendo pruebas.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133012/discussion-on-question-by-braylin-ivan-payano-error-al-enviar-mis-mensajes-con-l).